# MongoDB compare users based on nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nestjs

I have a collection of users with nested array Answers. I need to compare their responses, every time that it is the same i add the coeff value of the answers to a variable, then if for example it's above 10 i send back all the users with their own total coeff (above 10 so).

So question is how to compare users by going to a nested array (answers) checking if the same field have the same value (answerChoice) for the same answer (answerNumber) and taking another value of the nested array (answerCoeff) to increment into a variable and printing the total coeff and the users meeting a certain coeff amount

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "birthdate": "2021-06-18T13:53:30.443Z",
  "userName": "string",
  "pictures": [
    "string"
  ],
  "answers": [
    {
      "answerNumber": 0,
      "answerChoice": 3,
      "answerCoeff": 2
    },
    {
      "answerNumber": 1,
      "answerChoice": 2,
      "answerCoeff": 5
    }
     ...
  ],
}
```

Output expected :

```
{
  "matchs": [
    {
      "ids": [
        "string"
      ],
      "userName": "string",
      "pictures": [
        "string"
      ],
      "coeff": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more specific and clear information on what is that you'd like to achieve, and what you have tried to solve the issue. I don't understand your goal and problem here.

Comment: I tried to be the most specific about it, but i'll update my question

Comment: so you want to compare the `answerCoeff`? could you please provide us with the value you are using to compare it with ?

Comment: also mention the logic of comparison. Like do you take the sum of answerCoeff of all answers, or you do individual comparison

Comment: No i just updated my question ! i want to compare every question they must have the same answerChoice and by the end i want the sum of answerCoeff that matched

Comment: where is your code ?show the code